# Topojson command on .shp file not working?

Tags: makefile, topojson

thanks for reading this; I could use some help.

I read this [article](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/make/), it is about creating a makefile to convert a [topojson](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson) file from a .shp file. I am following the steps contained in downloadable Makefile available whithin the article's link, however I simply can't get to create the .json file; it just doesn't appear. These are the steps I am trying to replicate:

```
    curl -o counties.zip 'http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2010/gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.zip'
    unzip counties.zip
    touch gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.shp
    topojson -o counties.json -- counties=gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.shp
```

Step 4 is simply not working. I have no reason to think topojson is not properly installed, although I have never been able to create a topojson file. What could be wrong?

After downloading the Makefile and executing it in order to convert the topojson file the following message is displayed in the terminal:

> topojson -o counties.json -- counties=gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.shp
>   make: *** [counties.json] Error 1

These are some of my PC's specifications:

- I am running Ubuntu on  Oracle virtualbox v4.3.26, my main OS is Windows 8 64 bit.
- Intel Celeron 1.90 GHz
- 4.00 GB Ram.

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: I assume the unzipped .shp name is correct since `touch` doesn't fail. Then, try to simplify the output via `-q 1e4`. It gives `topojson -q 1e4 -o counties.json -- counties=gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.shp` it may help.

Comment: Still not working. topojson -q 1e4 -o counties.json -- counties=gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.shp
make: *** [counties.json] Error 1

Comment: Not working either, both when the command is executed and the Makefile is run. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Process validation

Your / The following commands are correct :

```
curl -o counties.zip 'http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2010/gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.zip'
unzip counties.zip
touch gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.shp
topojson -o counties.json -- counties=gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.shp
```

Running it is successful :

[image]

Visualisation is fine :

[image]

File is visible, to inspect, and downloable [there, on jsoneditoronline.org](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=481a42ba922cd1a107f2366faca9d662).

#### Way to go

Did you ever produced a single topojson file via the command line topojson script ? If not, I guess topojson is either not installed or corrupted. There is a common issue with some dependency. I advice you to uninstall topojson, then to reinstall it.

#### Bug repporting

Please report the error message you get when running `topojson -o counties.json -- counties=gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.shp` without makefile. So we get a `topojson` or `npm` error, not the `make` error.

#### Next

Search for "how to install topojson + bug". Example : [Trouble installing topojson on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18045124/)

Comment: Thank you very much! I had to reinstall Ubuntu on my machine. Great tips!